# How to set a label to the default color globally?

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, set, label

C# -> Windows Forms

In the past I've set as a descriptor:

```
Color gcolorBackDialogBox;
Color gcolorForeDialogBox;
```

Under dlg_Load() I've defined them as:

```
gcolorBackDialogBox = this.BackColor;
gcolorForeDialogBox = this.ForeColor;
```

Under a function I've used them as:

```
gLBlStatus.BackColor = gcolorBackDialogBox;
gLBlStatus.ForeColor = gcolorForeDialogBox;
```

### where gLBlStatus is the name of a label on a dialog box.  This sets the label to the same color as the dialog box.

I'm converting to C# -> WPF.  I can change the labels:

```
gLBlStatus.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
gLBlStatus.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
```

but can't find a way to replicate the global aspect.

I've found that the default dialog box color is SystemColors.ControlBrushKey ... am unable to find a way to make this nomenclature work.

Comment: If you are rewriting your WinForms application, I'd recommend using different techniques to achieve the same result. If you want all your labels to have the same colour, you can do that using Styles. You can even create a global style in the app.xaml file that will apply to all windows within your application.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create a `SolidColorBrush` global instance,

```
SolidColorBrush gcolorBackDialogBox = new SolidColorBrush(color);
SolidColorBrush gcolorForeDialogBox = new SolidColorBrush(color);
```

There are other classes that inherit from [`Brush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for different styles of color.

Comment: I tried your suggestion ... what do I enter for "color"?  I tried using "Brushes.Blue" ... it didn't like that.

Comment: Look at the documentation: it takes a `Color` class instance.